# Wingpanel disappears when opening spotify

Tags: release-loki, spotify

I've been using Elementary OS (loki) for a few days now, and I initially had no problems. The only strange thing I noticed is that apt update was throwing some weird errors because it was targeting loki distribution instead of xenial. After I changed this and installed updates, the problem began.

When I open the Spotify client, the wingpanel bar disappears

It seems similar to this issue [Spotify crashing the wingpanel (loki)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/spotify-crashing-the-wingpanel-loki)

It seems to be the case that if I close spotify and press super + space, the wingbar returns. However, it does not return while the client is open. What is particularly annoying is that it was working perfectly fine before I installed the updates.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Try using 'killall wingpanel'

Comment: I tried that, I just get the response `wingpanel: no process found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix this by re installing noise (the music player), which I had previously removed. Presumably when I removed it I also removed a library which the sound notification in the wingpanel relied on.

Comment: You are a saviour!