# Elementary Loki crashes frequently

Tags: release-loki, crash

Recent (second) clean install of Loki freezes intermittently.  If left running, it would freeze 4-8 times per day.  If there is music playing, the music will sometimes continue normally while the screen is frozen, sometimes "skip"/1/2 second loop.  How to fix this stability issue?

Comment: Just found https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/spotify-crashing-the-wingpanel-loki.  Wondering if this is the same issue, so I have tried:

sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-sound

I'll update if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried running an Arch system via live USB and it crashed the same way elementary has been.  I conclude it must be a hardware issue.